# Restlet Jetty Extension with Keycloak Client Adapter

Tags: java, keycloak, embedded-jetty, restlet

A backend Rest Server with **restlet** and **jetty extension** (embedded jetty server) [1] is running.

The need arose to extract an Authorization Server from the application (there is a deprecated self-made OAuth version embedded). The consideration is to use **Keycloak** for this purpose.

How do I integrate the **Client Adapter**? [2] Is this possible?

[1] https://restlet.talend.com/documentation/user-guide/2.4/extensions/jetty
[2] https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_jetty9_adapter

Comment: Try here: https://gitter.im/restlet-framework/community